# How to check (withtrigger) if a table on creation is already referenced by another table in a PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, create-table

I am setting up a database which can check at each table creation if the name given is referenced in a table called core_metadata. For this purpose, I  added a trigger thats is fired on table creation. But I am still stuck with this error when I try to CREATE a new table in the database (error message is returned by the trigger function).

My function code is the following:

```
DECLARE created_table record;    
DECLARE name_check varchar(255);
DECLARE namedd varchar(255);
DECLARE checked integer;

BEGIN
    checked := 0;
    FOR created_table IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag in ('CREATE TABLE','CREATE TABLE AS','ALTER TABLE')
    LOOP    
        namedd  := created_table.object_identity;
        SELECT referenced_tables.object_identity INTO name_check FROM 
        (SELECT CONCAT('public.',data_table) AS object_identity FROM core_metadata) AS referenced_tables 
        WHERE referenced_tables.object_identity = namedd;

        IF name_check THEN 
            checked := 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF checked = 0 THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Table must be first defined into core_metadata (%)', checked;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table added to metadata (%)',checked;
    END IF;
END;
```

HINT: I replaced the mention *namedd* by NULL, and the error disappeared. But as long as the variable *checked* stay equal to 0, my function does not work as expected.

```
DECLARE created_table record;    
DECLARE name_check varchar(255);
DECLARE namedd varchar(255);
DECLARE checked integer := 0;

BEGIN
    FOR created_table IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag in ('CREATE TABLE','CREATE TABLE AS','ALTER TABLE')
    LOOP    
        namedd  := created_table.object_identity;
        SELECT referenced_tables.object_identity INTO name_check FROM 
        (SELECT CONCAT('public.',data_table) AS object_identity FROM core_metadata) AS referenced_tables 
        WHERE referenced_tables.object_identity = NULL ;

        IF name_check THEN 
            checked := 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF checked = 0 THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Table must be first defined into core_metadata (%)', checked;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table added to metadata (%)',checked;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found the following solution:

```
DECLARE checked integer := 0;
DECLARE r record;
DECLARE t record;

BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
    LOOP    
        FOR t IN SELECT CONCAT('public.',data_table) AS object_identity FROM core_metadata
        LOOP
            IF r.object_identity =  t.object_identity THEN
                checked := 1;
            ELSE
                RAISE NOTICE '% - %', r.object_identity, t.object_identity;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    IF checked = 0 THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Table must be first defined into core_metadata (%)', checked;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table added to metadata (%)',checked;
    END IF;
END;
```